# I'm having problems with pickle

Tags: python, pickle

so , while I'm just dabbling in coding, and just experimenting, I wanted to create a database that was easy to interact with for the 170 (for now) NPCs that my D&D campaign is gonna require.

Turns out, mashing together pieces of code without understanding them doesn't always work, shocker.

So, here's my code, though I'm sure it'll make your eyes bleed, I just need to make it work:

```
#import pickle
import pickle

#NPC ID generator 
counter=1
NPCS=[]
while counter<=170 :
    NPCS.append(counter)
    counter+=1


if len(NPCS)==170:
    print ("True")
else :
    print ("False") ; raise SystemExit 

#Attributes
name=[] ; occupation=[];weakness=[];need=[];desire=[];enemy=[];rumor=[];secret=[];passion=[]
redeemdamningquality=[];happy=[];occdesire=[];occcomplication=[];pcopinion=[];accomplish=[]
magical=[];politinfl=[];resource=[];intel=[];research=[]

NPCatt=[name,occupation,weakness,need,desire,enemy,rumor,secret,passion,redeemdamningquality,happy,occdesire,occcomplication,pcopinion, accomplish,magical,politinfl,resource,intel,research]  

#open a pickle file
newfile = 'NPCatt.pk'
#load your data back to memory when you need it
with open(newfile, 'rb') as fi:
  NPCatt = pickle.load(fi)

# Data Input 
print ("Enter the numerical code of the NPC you wish to modify")
raw=int(input())

if raw != ValueError :
    print ("Enter Name of NPC" + str(raw) ) ; a=input()
    if a!="":
        name.insert(raw+1,a);print ("Name Inserted Successfully")
    else:
        print ("Skipped!")

    print ("Enter Occupation of NPC" + str(raw) ) ;a=input()
    if a!="":
        occupation.insert(raw+1,a);print("Occupation Inserted Successfully")
    else:
        print ("Skipped!")
else :
    print ("BAD VALUE")

for x in (NPCatt) :
    if len(x)!=0 :
         print (x)
    elif len(x)>=170:
        print (x) ; print ("Has too many items")
    else :
        print (str(x) + "is empty")




with open(newfile, 'wb') as fi:
  # dump your data into the file
  pickle.dump(NPCatt, fi)
```

What I'm not sure about is why the data I input is not "saved" between code runs. 
Please help

Comment: can you make a minimum reproducable example of your problem. Currently if i try loading a pickled object, modifying it then pickling it back to file again and again the changes do get saved.

Comment: Honestly Chris, I wouldn't know how. I can tell you that the code runs without error or exceptions, it just does not save the data I want it to.

Comment: I haven't, how might I?

Comment: Its not file system issue. its an issue with how the OP understood varaibles to be working.

Comment: @Icarus I had a look through your code and spotted the issue and have posted an answer which explains why it happens and how you can change it to work in your current code but also suggested as you might have guessed that this code is not the best way to do this

Comment: @ChrisDoyle , thanks for looking through my mess of a code, you've been a great help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your issue is your understanding of how variables and assignments work. In the code below you makes lots of lists. you then create a variable called NPCatt which has references to all these lists you created.

```py
#Attributes
name=[] ; occupation=[];weakness=[];need=[];desire=[];enemy=[];rumor=[];secret=[];passion=[]
redeemdamningquality=[];happy=[];occdesire=[];occcomplication=[];pcopinion=[];accomplish=[]
magical=[];politinfl=[];resource=[];intel=[];research=[]

NPCatt=[name,occupation,weakness,need,desire,enemy,rumor,secret,passion,redeemdamningquality,happy,occdesire,occcomplication,pcopinion, accomplish,magical,politinfl,resource,intel,research]
```

So if i was to look at NPCatt[0] it would be a list of all the npc names. which is fine. However you then go on to do

```py
with open(newfile, 'rb') as fi:
  NPCatt = pickle.load(fi)
```

now the variable NPCatt doesnt point to all your lists. It points now to the unpickled object. so when you later do names.append it will update the names list but NPCatt no longer points to this list. so when you pickle NPCatt your pickling only that which you loaded from the file.

This is the crux of your error. if you wanted to modify the data the NPCatt holds after you unpickle it then you should access it like

```
   if a!="":
        NPCatt[0].insert(raw+1,a);print ("Name Inserted Successfully")
    else:
        print ("Skipped!")

    print ("Enter Occupation of NPC" + str(raw) ) ;a=input()
    if a!="":
        NPCatt[1].insert(raw+1,a);print("Occupation Inserted Successfully")
    else:
        print ("Skipped!")
```

However this becomes very messy and its not clear which list is being updated since you have to refer to it by index position. you would be better to look at python dictionary here instead as you can then refer to things by name rather than index position. Or even better if yor up for it look at creating an NPC class and then store each NPC in a dict by NPC_ID: NPC_CLASS_INSTANCE

**UPDATE**

Below is just a quick example i threw together using a class for the npc and a dict to store the npcs by id. This was just put together without any real though around design or pro's and con's its just done to show you as an example.

```py
# import pickle
import pickle
npcs_pickle_file = 'NPCatt.pk'
npc_count = 170

class NPC:
    def __init__(self, name="", occupation="", weakness="", need="", desire="", enemy="",
                 rumor="", secret="", passion="", redeem_damning_quality="", happy="",
                 occ_desire="", occ_complication="", pc_opinion="", accomplish="", magical="",
                 politinfl="", resource="", intel="", research=""):

        # Attributes
        self.name = name
        self.occupation = occupation
        self.weakness = weakness
        self.need = need
        self.desire = desire
        self.enemy = enemy
        self.rumor = rumor
        self.secret = secret
        self.passion = passion
        self.redeem_damning_quality = redeem_damning_quality
        self.happy = happy
        self.occ_desire = occ_desire
        self.occ_complication = occ_complication
        self.pc_opinion = pc_opinion
        self.accomplish = accomplish
        self.magical = magical
        self.politinfl = politinfl
        self.resource = resource
        self.intel = intel
        self.research = research

    def __str__(self):
        npc_output = "####NPC SUMMARY####\n"
        for att, val in self.__dict__.items():
            if val:
                npc_output += (f"{att} = {val}\n")
        return npc_output

# open a pickle file
# load your data back to memory when you need it
try:
    with open(npcs_pickle_file, 'rb') as fi:
        npcs = pickle.load(fi)
except FileNotFoundError as fne:
    #file doesnt exist prob first time running so create a dict with the 170 npc id's
    npcs = {id: None for id in range(npc_count)}


#select an NPC to modify / create
npc_id = None
while not npc_id:
    try:
        npc_id = int(input(f"Enter the id number of the NPC you wish to modify: "))
    except ValueError as ve:
        print("You must provide a numerical id")

    if npc_id < 0 or npc_id >= npc_count:
        npc_id = None
        print(f"you must provide a value between 0 and {npc_count}")

name = input("Enter name of NPC: ")
occupation = input("Enter NPC occupation: ")

if npcs[npc_id]:
    npc = npcs[npc_id]
    print(npc)
    modify = input("This NPC already exists do you want to continue and change them? (y/n): ")
    if modify.lower() == "y":
        npc.name = name
        npc.occupation = occupation
else:
    npcs[npc_id] = NPC(name=name, occupation=occupation)

print(npcs[npc_id])
with open(npcs_pickle_file, 'wb') as fi:
    # dump your data into the file
    pickle.dump(npcs, fi)
```

Comment: Alright, I'll look into classes and dictionaries then, thank you for simplifying the issue so I could understand  ^.^

Comment: @Icarus I have updated my answer with an example of how you could use class / dict for storing npcs

Comment: Oh my! Thank you so much! I'll be messing with your example to learn how it works, this is a goldmine for me :D

Answer (score -1):

I know this is not at all what you're asking for, but wouldn't it be much easier for you to use a spreadsheet for this?

You're manually entering the data and stuffing it into a 2D data-structure anyway.
If you need to use the data elsewhere, save the spreadsheet as a .csv file and import that.

Comment: It would, absolutely. But this is a way for me to dabble in coding while solving an irl problem